# Excel VBA Find Function

Tags: excel, vba

Okay so, I am new to VBA and excel, but I am working on code that is taking a list of trainings from one sheet, checks them from the trainings I have copied over. That part works completely fine, the problem I am running into is th when it tries to find a training that is not on the second sheet. It just ends, and I have not been able to find anything on google to help. Attached are an example of what the two sheets would look like, just without all of the trainings and names.

Sheet 1 Table of names and trainings that have been complete

[image: 1]

Sheet 2 trainings that sheet 1 checks against in the code

[image: 2]

Any assistance is appreciated.

```vb
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Test 1]]").Select
        Selection.Copy
```

The first part of the code copies then name of training one. example: (Training 1)

```vb
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Cells.Find(What:="Test 1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
```

The second part then switches to sheet 2 and uses the find function and pastes the name of the training to see if there is one that matches, and if it does match it will have a date attached to it for when the training expires. It then copies the new training name and date format. Example: (Training 1 (2023-3-04))
This is where I am facing a problem, when it goes to use the find command, and it tries to find a training that doesn't exist in sheet two because it either hasn't been done or has expired the macro ends and throws up an error. What I am wanting to know is. Is there a way to make make it where if it finds nothing then it skips to the next part of the code?
The code here will be copied and pasted with the trainings name changed 25+ times.

```vb
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range( _
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), _
            Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column) _
        )
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End Sub
```

The last part then takes what it copies over from sheet two (Training 1 (2024-3-04) and copies it right below the training header.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuV2o.jpg): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuV2o.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your expected output. What content do you want to copy from Sheet2 to Sheet1?

Answer (score 1):

- Note: `Find(What:="Test 1",..LookAt:=xlPart )` matches not only `Test 1 ..` but also `Test 11 ...`. It's not reliable for your case.
- Use Dictionary object to get the training list

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008907)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey As String, arrData
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' load data from sheet2
    arrData = oSht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load into Dict
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = Trim(Split(arrData(i, 1), "(")(0))
        If Not objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ' load data from sheet2
    Set rngData = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' loop throught data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            sKey = arrData(1, j)
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                arrData(i, j) = objDic(sKey)
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    ' write output to sheet1
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

[image]

Btw, it's worth to read:

> [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

Answer (score 0):

@taller's answer is much more robust, but this may be easier to help you understand what's happening:

Your code is currently trying to `.Activate` the result of the `.Find` method, regardless of whether or not something is found. You can't activate a cell if no cell is found, hence the error.

Instead, split this into 2 steps. First check if the `.Find` method finds a cell. If it does, then `.Activate` the cell.

```
Dim Result As Range

Sheets("Sheet2").Select

'Assign the result of .Find to a variable called Result
Set Result = Cells.Find(What:="Test 1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'Check if Result exists
If Not Result Is Nothing Then
    
    'The code you want to run if you find a matching cell should go here
    Result.Activate
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    
End If

'The code you want to skip to if you don't find a matching cell should go here

End Sub
```